# Android unable to load correct oriented image from gallery

Tags: java, android, image, opencv, orientation

I am loading an image from gallery through bitmap api but the orientation of the image comes different than the one i saved it. Somewhere on stackoverflow i read that i need to get the oreintation value and then rotate the matrix. I tried this but my orientation is coming as 0 from the exif interface.

```
        int desiredImageWidth = 310;  // pixels
        int desiredImageHeight = 518; // pixels

        Log.i("FA", "Image Loading "+strFileName);
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strFileName, o), 
                                                   desiredImageWidth, 
                                                   desiredImageHeight, 
                                                   false);

        Bitmap finalBmp = getCorrectOrientedBitmap(strFileName,newImage);

        Bitmap myBitmap32 = finalBmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Mat matImg = Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32);
```

My main orientation function is

```
    private Bitmap getCorrectOrientedBitmap(String filename,Bitmap Source) throws IOException{

    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filename);
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Log.i("FA", "orientation "+orientation);
    switch(orientation)
    {
    case 6:
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        break;
    case 3:
        matrix.postRotate(180);
        break;
    case 8:
        matrix.postRotate(270);
        break;
    }
    rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Source, 0, 0, Source.getWidth(), Source.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    return rotatedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: I am also running into same problem. but in my case some of the pic from gallery comes in different orientation. can you post your solution that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting `0` back from `getAttributeInt`, then I think that just means your "rotated" image doesn't have any orientation info stored in it.  You could independently double check with an online tool or download a good image viewer to find out.

Have you tried this code on another device?  Is it possible that your test device doesn't save the orientation tag?

[This page](http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/08/rotating-images-in-android/) has some nice sample code to do what you're trying to do, maybe you could find some improvements as well there.